# Convert image coordinate to cartesian coordinates

Tags: image, matlab, coordinates

Given a image canvas I with 2 points (a_x, a_y) and (b_x, b_y). The plotted line on the image has the correct orientation.
However, when I plot the same coordinates (a and b) in a cartesian coordinate system, I get a line with the wrong orientation.
I would like to convert the image coordinates that they match with the cartesian system. Thanks.

```
% Create image canvas
canvas = zeros(320, 320);
I = uint8(canvas);
imshow(I)
a_x = 122.6544;
a_y = 234.9782;
b_x = 165.9290;
b_y = 126.9200;
hold on 
plot([a_x, b_x], [a_y, b_y] )
% Plot cartesian coordinate system
figure()
plot([a_x, b_x], [a_y, b_y])
xlim([0 320])
ylim([0 320])
axis equal
grid on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images generated by `imshow` have the `(0,0)` coordinate at the upper left corner. Normal plots at the lower left corner.

You can see this by switching on the axes of the image:

```
% Create image canvas
canvas = zeros(320, 320);
I = uint8(canvas);
imshow(I)
a_x = 122.6544;
a_y = 234.9782;
b_x = 165.9290;
b_y = 126.9200;
hold on 
plot([a_x, b_x], [a_y, b_y] );

ax = gca;
ax.Visible = 'on';
```

To change the direction of the plot axes, use the `YDir` property of the `axes`:

```
figure()
plot([a_x, b_x], [a_y, b_y])
xlim([0 320])
ylim([0 320])
grid on

ax=gca;
ax.YDir = 'reverse';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works. I guess the calculations (e.g. distance) won't be affected by the axis direction. Can you please confirm?

Comment: The coordinates don't change, thus I guess your calculations won't change either.